# Concatenate string at last character

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to find a way to concatenate a string after the last character, not by the size or spaces.

The input would be something like this: `XXXX    ;0;1; YYYY AA`            
I wan to add after the last character the string `;S`. Is there a way of doing it without redefining the entire field? It would take some hours to refactor the entire code.

I'm using MicroFocus(NetExpress) cobol compiler.

Comment: Hi Toniotti and welcome to SO. I suggest to expand the question a bit specifying the code that declares the data and how it gets in there currently (`MOVE`/`STRING`?), then we have a better understanding how your concatenation is intended and where it may be added. (or if it needs to be inserted in the final data after everything is done, like your answer suggest, but that wouldn't be concatenation but replacement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the length of function combined with reference-modification to avoid redefine, string or other boilerplate code in COBOL.

Define a variable to store your string `XXXX    ;0;1; YYYY AA`            :

```
working-storage section.
01  given-string    pic x(40)
                    value "XXXX    ;0;1; YYYY AA            ".
```

Using **length of** function and **ref-modification** in one line:

```
procedure division.
main section.

    display "given-string (before): " ">" given-string "<"

    move ";S" to given-string(length of given-string - 1:2)

    display "given-string (after) : " ">" given-string "<"
```

Output **before**:

```
given-string (before): >XXXX    ;0;1; YYYY AA                   <
```

Output **after**:

```
given-string (after) : >XXXX    ;0;1; YYYY AA                 ;S<
```

btw...
For better representation I've used 40 Bytes instead of 900. But the logic is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just writing the question i thought about something, i posted and run to try it out. It did not solve the problem in the way i wanted, but solved it.

What i did was redefining the string with an filler.

```
fd  YOUR-FD.                                         
01  THE-STRING                    pic x(900).        
                                                               
01  filler redefines YOUR-FD.                     
    03 filler                     pic x(898).        
    03 CONCAT                     pic x(02).         
       88 HAS-CONCAT              value ";S".
```